# Is integral convergent? $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x} \sin(2x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I have a problem with following integral:
$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x} \sin(2x)dx$
I was trying to prove convergence (or divergence) of this integral, however without any success.

My best guess at this time is that this integral is not convergent, but I have no proof of that.

Comment: Convergence as an improper Riemann integral? So the question is whether $$\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_1^T \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\sin (2x)\,dx$$ exists?

Comment: Yes, that is the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

We have
$$\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x}\sin(2x)\sim_\infty \frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt x}$$
Now we integrate by parts we get

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt x}dx=-\frac12\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt x}\Bigg|_1^\infty-\frac14\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos(2x)}{x^{3/2}}dx$$
and clearly that the last integral is convergent so the given integral is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try applying [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_Integrals). I will leave it to you to break the integrand into two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** With the change of variable $y=\sqrt x$, your integral becomes:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2y^2}{1+y^2}\sin(2y^2)dy=2\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin(2y^2)dy-2\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}\sin(2y^2)dy\ .$$
The first one is a Fresnel integral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Split the integral up in small intervals with $X_0 = [1,\pi/2]$, $X_j= [\pi j/2, \pi(j+1)/2]$, $j=1,...,N$. We have $I= \sum_{j=0}^N I_j$ with $I_j= \int_{X_j} dx \sqrt{x} \sin(2 x)/(1+x)$ and $N\to \infty$.
- Find a bound of the absolute value of $I_j$ (this should be easy be observing that $\sqrt{x}/(1+x)$ is monotonously decreasing on $x\in [1,\infty]$. You should find a bound which goes to 0 for $j\to \infty$.
- Observe that the sum $\sum_j I_j$ is alternating and apply Dirichlets criterion.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Sami Ben Romdhane's answer, you could notice that,for large value of $x$, $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}$$ and arrive to Sami Ben Romdhane's conclusions.